# Sharing session between Servlets and Struts 2 application issue

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets, struts2

I am saving an session attribute in my action class and retrieving it in my servlet.

However, it seems that I encounter occasional session attribute missing problem.

How can I debug this issue?

**Struts 2 Action Code**

```
private Map<String, Object> map ;

public void setSession(Map<String, Object) session) {
   map = session ;
}

map.put("MY_OBJECT", object);
```

**Servlet Code**

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
Object obj = session.getAttribute("MY_OBJECT");
```

Comment: Did you debug your code to check whether the same session is being used and whether you actually get a `SessionMap` passed to `setSession()`, as well as the order of the calls?

Comment: How do I debug into struts framework?

Comment: This issue happens occasionally, all the while I have been using IE developer tools to track the session cookie values. Although, I knew the session seems to be replaced, but I have no idea why.

Comment: You debug a struts application like you'd debug any other application, e.g. by starting the JVM with debug options that let the debugger hook into it via some port. Ofc you also need the struts sources for meaningful debugging of struts itself. As for the cookie replacement have a look at the settings like cookie path, secure flag etc.

Comment: My cookie path and secure cookie are not set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try using SessionAware interface implementation for this . For more help see below link.

http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/struts/working-with-httpsession-in-struts2-a-login-example

Comment: I am already using it.